# babel polyfill breaks with webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, babel-polyfill

I am trying to start a new project, with webpack, and babel-polyfill, but it keeps giving me these errors, I tried finding a solution online but I was unsuccessfull:

error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/js/index.js' in 'C:\Users\Arian\Desktop\Daily Planner 2.0'
 @ multi babel-polyfill ./src/js/index.js main[1]

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 babel-polyfill ./src/js/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/js/index.js' in 'C:\Users\Arian\Desktop\Daily Planner 2.0'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 babel-polyfill ./src/js/index.js main[2]
```

here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/js/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "js/bundle.js",
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist",
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "index.html",
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_module/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Sorry to say it. You completely misunderstood whole thing. Babel should only be used as a loader to transpile whole your sources based on defined preset. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts/ and https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/

Comment: ok thanks I'll check it out